# ¿Cómo hacer pantalla de level complete entre escenas?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Tengo una pregunta la cual espero me puedan ayudar a resolver

¿Como podría hacer una pantalla entre niveles la cual me ayude a cambiar el nivel?

Actualmente lo hice con un `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildindex + 1)`

Lo cual me había funcionado hasta que agregue un 3er nivel ya que al estar la escena solo entre el nivel 1 y 2 al querer pasar al 3er nivel me regresa al nivel 2

Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Mejor carga las escenas por el nombre o asegúrate de que en `Build settings` se encuentran todas las escenas que necesitas y en el orden correcto.